# FastAPI - How to use HTTPException in responses?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

The documentation suggests raising an HTTPException with client errors, which is great.
But how can I show those specific errors in the documentation following HTTPException's model? Meaning a dict with the "detail" key.

The following does not work because HTTPException is not a Pydantic model.

```
@app.get(
    '/test', 
    responses={
        409 : {
            'model' : HTTPException, 
            'description': 'This endpoint always raises an error'
        }
    }
)
def raises_error():
    raise HTTPException(409, detail='Error raised')
```

Comment: Wouldn't an  [`example`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/additional-responses/#combining-information) do that? If not, can you show us how it would look like in the swagger doc?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes it is not a valid Pydantic type however since you can create your own models, it is easy to create a Model for it.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Dummy(BaseModel):
    name: str


class HTTPError(BaseModel):
    detail: str

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {"detail": "HTTPException raised."},
        }


app = FastAPI()


@app.get(
    "/test",
    responses={
        200: {"model": Dummy},
        409: {
            "model": HTTPError,
            "description": "This endpoint always raises an error",
        },
    },
)
def raises_error():
    raise HTTPException(409, detail="Error raised")
```

I believe this is what you are expecting

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, I was wondering why I couldn't get the error to show in the swagger docs. I see you need to add in the `responses:` arg.

Comment: for 200 status, you can use the `response_model`. Also, one note: whatever models you add in responses, FastAPI does not validate it with your actual response for that code. It's just for the swagger.